# How to create dynamic components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I see opportunities to minimize network bytes transfer of my website, but can't come up with a proper solution.

In Gatsby, I make use of .mdx files. In these files I can use React Components, such as:
`<Cards id="id_1" />`

There are dozens of cards defined in a .json file, which can be used across the website by just calling this component in de mdx file and passing their id.

The Cards component looks like somewhat like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import Img from 'gatsby-image';
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby';


const Cards = (props) => {
    const card_id = props.id ? props.id.slice(0, 2) : []  // grab id

    return <StaticQuery
        query={graphql`
        query Query  {
                    images: allFile(filter: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "card-images" } }) {
                        edges {
                            node {
                                childImageSharp {
                                    fluid(maxHeight: 256, quality: 100) {
                                        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
                                        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluidLimitPresentationSize
                                    }
                                }
                                name
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    allCardsJson {
                        nodes {
                            name
                            id
                        }
                    }
                }
        `}
        render={(data) => {
            
            return(
               // returns a component by filtering 'data' by 'card_id'
            )
        }}
    />
}
```

Everything works fine, but...

When this component is used, the **full result of StaticQuery** (meaning: all cards since filtering is done inside the return, not inside the staticquery) is send to visitors of the page. This is unnecessary and a waste of network bandwidth, because for example only one card (or a few) is used on the page.

I understand that a StaticQuery is .. static. Thus, I cannot dynamically filter within this query to limit the size of the result.

DynamicQuerys are used when building pages, not inside components.

Is it possible to somehow create components with dynamic content (defined elsewhere), but limited to just the required data? (like by providing an id like I've tried)

I am thinking about creating a seperate file for each Card. Then import the Cards needed into the mdx file and passing it to the component. Thoughts?

There is no documentation about my use case. This makes me wonder if I'm using it as intended.

Comment: Have you taken a look at useStaticQuery hook? https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/use-static-query/

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/data-fetching/ ... of course you can create many json files (or fetch some api using axios; runtime fetching), one per created page ... if only for build time you can pass filtered data entry by context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding the used data to the page context by editing the gatsby-node.js:

1. Get the mdxAST of the post, filter the  components, then filter the ids used.
2. Add this list of ids to the page context.
3. Move the query stated in the question above to the post GraphQL query. Use the list of ids provided by page context to filter the data down to only the used ids in this post.
4. Pass this data as a property to the MDXRenderer.
5. Pass this data in the .mdx file to the cards component, such as: `<Cards data={props.cards_data} />`.
6. Now the compontent received the data without using a StaticQuery.

This works, but it feels kinda weird. There must be a better, more clean, solution in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

GraphQL queries are run ONCE when you run `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build`. This is a counterintuitive way how Gatsby works but [read it yourself](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/graphql-concepts/#how-do-graphql-and-gatsby-work-together):

> Gatsby uses GraphQL at build-time and not for live sites.

[More information about the gatsby build process](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/overview-of-the-gatsby-build-process/) and how GraphQL factors into it.

This means you already built your component the way you are supposed to. **During build** all your cards are queried and kept in memory. When creating the HTML for your pages with your cards, **only the cards with your ID** are used to build your page. Thus the user only sees gets transmitted the pages with filtered IDs.

You can double check if really only the cards with the ID are inside your page:

- run `gatsby clean`: make sure old fragments of your page are removed
- run `gatsby build`: Create your site from scratch
- Check your `public` folder in your project root. This is the classic webpage that gatsby builds. Navigate to your pages with your cards for example `/public/blog/example-page-with-card`. Take a look inside the HTML of the page: Does it contain all the cards or just the one with the IDs you need?

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have found this to be invalid. During build, the complete result of the static query is written to a JSON file in /page-data/sq/*.json. This file is loaded by every visitor. It includes all the cards, not just the ones used in the components, which leads to an unnecessary amount of data transfer.

Maybe I did something wrong, idk. Therefore, I was wondering how I could filter this down to just the IDs used on the page.

I sort of solved it (see answer). I am curious about your opinion.